# Pattern expression for digit.digit.digit?

Tags: java, regex

I, im doing a pattern regular expression for check if a String is:

digit.digit.digit like this:

```
1.1.1
0.20.2
58.55541.5221
```

In java i use this:

```
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*.\\d*.\\d*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

But if i pass
20.20. return me true in matches.

What is grond?

Comment: What is `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` doing in matching digits?

Comment: @RohitJain For lowercase and uppercase digits obviously!

Comment: @TheZ.. Heard it first time. ;)

Comment: @colymore - I can't say for sure, since I don't know what your code is being used for, but I suggest you evaluate if `String.matches(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)` would do. --- Using `Pattern` and `Matcher` directly creates new objects, with a small performance penalty. --- Although it uses them internally (since it's a regex too), `String.matches()` is done through a Java's internal `static` method, which has the instances already pre-allocated. It's a small improvement that many would call *"premature optimization"*, but if you are dealing with many runs &/or lots of data, it makes a big difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `+` instead of `*`. `*` is 0 or more repetitions, while `+` is 1 or more repetitions.

Additionally, don't forget to escape the `.` characters:

```
"\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+"
```

Comment: zzzzBov got the answer first

Comment: You beat Rohit's answer by 27 seconds, but he's has a slightly better format in my opinion. --- Still, for the same reasons, a [+1] is in order. =)

Comment: It is more important to upvote an answer based on its utility than it is to upvote merely because it happened to be posted first.

Answer (score 6):

You have used `*` quantifier. which matches `0 or more repetition`.

Use `+` quantifier, which matches `1 or more repetition`: -

```
Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+");
```

Also, you need to escape your `dot(.)` as it has special meaning in `Regex`, which matches any character. So ,`.` in your regex, is not only matching `.`, it will match any character in fact.

Comment: I wanted to say I beat you to # code-chars with `(\d+\.){2}\d+`, but then I realized both are exactly the same length, at 13 characters. "-_- Anyways, [+1] for another well-explained regex answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the dot! It matches any Character, see [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

So you need

```
Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+");
```

I also replaced `*` with `+`, bacause `*` would also math 0 digits.

Answer (score 2):

zzzzBov suggestion is correct, and you also need to escape the `.`, so the correct regex would be

```
\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic regex you need

```
\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?
```

This will match the following

```
20.20.20
1.1.1
1.1.1
0.20.2
58.55541.5221
20.20
```

Comment: Err.. OP don't really want to match `20.20`. He just wants to match three numbers seperated by dot. `\d+\.\d+\.\d+`

Comment: It wasn't clear to me whether he wanted it or not so I included it.

Comment: @garyh.. Its fine. There is nothing wrong in learning new thing. This will certainly be helpful for OP. :)